# Get the distance between 2 points with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have the table A and B like this

[image]

As you can see I have 2 columns, lat and long, which are coordinates saved from Google API. The issue comes when I am trying to get the distance between the first and second table (the first table is a Client's current business location, and the second is an action table where every single reg has a new location, from a mobile device for example). Also, I am working with a library to build an XLS document therefor I can not use functions or code logic but SQL. If I can do it through a query I would solve my problem.

Do you know how to get the distance in meters between 2 points within SQL?

Comment: You apply a formula for distance,  What formula do you want to use?

Comment: Convert your scalar coordinates to geometry then apply https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance